# Can you run Docker natively on the new Windows 10 Linux kernel?

Tags: windows, docker, windows-10, linux-kernel, lxc

My understanding was that the primary limitation of running docker on other OSs was the Linux Network containers that made it possible. (Certainly for Macs).

Recently [Microsoft announced](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/shipping-a-linux-kernel-with-windows/) [a plan to provide](https://www.theverge.com/2019/5/6/18534687/microsoft-windows-10-linux-kernel-feature) [a Linux kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel) running [natively packaged](https://www.zdnet.com/article/windows-10-is-getting-a-microsoft-built-linux-kernel/) with Windows 10.

My question is: **Can you run Docker natively on the new Windows 10 Linux kernel?**

Note - this is not a duplicate of this question (which I also wrote) as that was about the [Windows 10 bash userspace](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2016/C906), and this is about the Windows 10 Linux kernel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible yes, it's one of the main "highlights" of Windows Subsystem for Linux 2. The main reason is that WSL 2 runs a Hyper-V container with the full Linux kernel, instead of just something that looks and feels like Linux like WSL 1 does.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/announcing-wsl-2/

Comment: Could you elaborate more on by a Hyper-V container makes the linux networking possible?

Comment: A Hyper-V container is something between a VM and a container, it runs it's own small copy of the chosen OS kernel, and as such behaves like a VM, and this is what enables networking. On the Windows side, it's basically like any other host running a Hyper-V VM with Linux in it.

Comment: So since it’s actually running the whole kernel, it runs docker natively, just as you can run docker on a Linux VM. There’s some other magic behind the Hyper-V containers, but for how it pertains to WSL and WSL2, that’s the gist of it.